Обработка потока из Form-Data с multipart/form-data на чистом Node.js
Мултер, написанный поверх экспресса – рабочее решение, но для обучения хочу поинтересоваться, а можно ли как-то обрабатывать multipart/form-data без этих двух библиотек? Обычный текст через потоки проходит на ура, а вот с картинками и прочими файлами уже туго.

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

multer написан поверх busboy-я. Так что почитайте исходники busboy.
Ну и RFC 7578 можно почитать.

Спасибо, почитаю
